# Text analyzation. Python beginner

Tags: macos, python-3.x, parsing, io

So I've just started a long way of python learning and encountered the following.
I have to create a program to count char in a text. Text is UTF-8 and I have to use .encoding='utf-8', but python says that 'keyword cant be an expression' and points out '(' before 'fn.encoding='utf-8'. I can't figure this out.

```
def count_char(text, char):
count=0
for c in text:
    if c==char:
        count+=1
    return count

fn=input('Enter a filename:')
with open (fn.encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text=f.read()

print(count_char(text,'a'))
```

Comment: replace the period with a comma. It's `open(file, encoding='utf-8')` not `open(file.encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: `fn,` not `fn.`.  Use a comma.

Comment: also move your `return` statement out a tab

Comment: Thank you, people! It's solved. 
But why, if i tab `return` it's ok for python and does not mark it as an error? I was thinking why it's not giving me the right answer...

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't play around with encoding/decoding files, but I do mess around with encodings for servers, from what I know I would do this. 
Instead of:

```
with open (fn.encoding='utf_8') as f:
```

I would do:

```
with open (fn.decode('utf_7') as f:
# your code here.
```

Answer (score 0):

First answer here, so be kind please. If you want to find how many "a" there are in a txt file, try to fix your code like this :

```
def count_char(text, char):
    count=0
    for c in text:
        if c==char:
            count+=1
    return count

fn=input('Enter a filename:')
with open (fn,encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text=f.read()

print(count_char(text,'a'))
```

as someone said, "return" should have been indented under "for", and the right way to express encoding is (fn, "r", "encoding=utf-8"). It was just a small indentation error, now it works! If you indent return under the if, you're telling the code to give you the count of letters found that are the same as "char" after getting out of the "if" statement, basically breaking the code after the first check it does on the condition. It's like telling him to check only for the first letter in your text. Try to test this by replacing the "char" with the first character in your text, you'll see the output will be "1". Please note that in this way you'll only be able to check for lowercase letters, you'll have to express it in a different way if you want to check both for lowercase and capital letters

```
def count_char(text, char1, char2):
    count=0
    for c in text:
        if c==char1 or c==char2:
            count+=1
    return count

fn=input('Enter a filename:')
with open (fn, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text=f.read()

print(count_char(text,'a','A'))
```

I'm a beginner too in python, I'm not so sure about using "or" here but it seems it's working!